# Can't connect to Tarantool container inside Docker through Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, tarantool

I want to connect to the tarantool cotainer using this code:

```
import TarantoolConnection from 'tarantool-driver'
let connection = new TarantoolConnection('192.168.99.100:3301');
connection.ping().then((res) => {
   console.log(res);
});
```

Before that i started container:

```
docker run -p 3301:3301 -d tarantool/tarantool:1.6
```

But in result i get nothing.

If i try to create space or\and index for this space:

```
connection.eval("box.schema.space.create('myspace', {if_not_exists=true, temporary=true})").then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

I get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: This socket is closed

or:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: connection will be destroyed or
>   already destroyed, create another one

As i see from the error, the needed socket is already closed, but i don't understand why.

Version of tarantool driver:

> ```
> "tarantool-driver": "2.0.5",
> ```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You should connect to `localhost:3301` instead of `192.168.99.100:3301`
2. You have to use `connection.connect()` before `connection.ping()` or `connection.eval()`

Here is the working code:

```
const TarantoolConnection = require('tarantool-driver');

let connection = new TarantoolConnection({port: 3301});

connection.connect().then((res) => {
    console.log("Connected: " + res);

    connection.ping().then((res) => {
        console.log("Pong: " + res);
    });

    connection.eval("box.schema.space.create('myspace', {if_not_exists=true, temporary=true})").then((res) => {
        console.log("Space created");
    });
});
```

Just in case, I've used the following command to start tarantool docker instance:

```
$ docker run --rm -p 3301:3301 -t -i tarantool/tarantool:1.6
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i still have the same error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3301. 
Other containers work fine and i can connect to them

Comment: That's rather strange. Looks like that the tarantool driver can't connect to the tarantool docker container. With running tarantool container, could you please try to connect to it in the other shell window using `telnet localhost 3301` and tell me the result?

Comment: That's really strange, because i can't even connect using telnet. I get the error: could not open connection to the host, using port 3301: connection error

Comment: But when i tried to connect uisng docker ip 192.168.99.100 it connected successfully (it it can be called so, because i get message like `Tarantool 1.6.9 (Binary) and strange sequence of symbols`)

Comment: Well, the message above is OK, it shows that you can connect to tarantool. Change in the third line of my code above `{port: 3301}` to `{host: '192.168.99.100', port: 3301}` and run it. It should work. The other question why port mapping to localhost doesn't work. Maybe there is something wrong with your docker setup. Could you please explain your OS and docker configuration?

Comment: Thank you! Finally, it worked. 
Btw, i use Windows 7 and docker toolbox, what may be the reason why i can't use localhost

Comment: thank you very much, your answer is much more clear than the actual readme on github